# Scrollview inside recyclerview not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I am using recyclerview with fragment. One of my fragment starts a new fragment which shows a doctor profile with image and long about me text. Everything working fine except vertical scrollview.
This is utterly learning purpose and im noob on this. Trying to learn how these works. I have attached fragment class, adapter and layout. Any type of reference, suggestion, correction can save me.
Thanks in advance.

Adapter

```
public class DoctorProfileAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DoctorProfileAdapter.DoctorProfileViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Doctors> doctorsList;

public DoctorProfileAdapter(Context mContext, List<Doctors> doctorsList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.doctorsList = doctorsList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public DoctorProfileViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.detail_doctor_profile, viewGroup, false);
    return new DoctorProfileViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final DoctorProfileViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Doctors doctors = doctorsList.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(doctors.getName());
    holder.degree.setText(doctors.getDegree());
    holder.specialty.setText(doctors.getSpecialty());
    holder.departments.setText(doctors.getDepartments());
    holder.bio.setText(doctors.getBio());
    Glide.with(mContext).load(doctors.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return doctorsList.size();
}

public class DoctorProfileViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView name, degree, departments, specialty, bio;
    public ImageView thumbnail;
    public DoctorProfileViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
       name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
       degree = view.findViewById(R.id.degree);
       departments = view.findViewById(R.id.department);
       specialty = view.findViewById(R.id.specialty);
       bio = view.findViewById(R.id.bio);
       thumbnail = view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    }
}
}
```

Fragment

```
public class DoctorProfileFragment extends Fragment {


private String ID, name, specialty, degree, thumbnail, departments, bio;

private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private ValueEventListener listener;
private DoctorProfileAdapter adapter;
private List<Doctors> list;
public DoctorProfileFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle("Profile");
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        ID = (String) bundle.getSerializable("id");
        name = (String) bundle.getSerializable("name");
        specialty = (String) bundle.getSerializable("specialty");
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blank_fragment, container, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    adapter = new DoctorProfileAdapter(getContext(), list);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    asyncTask();
    return view;
}

private void asyncTask(){
    databaseReference = databaseReference.child("doctors").child(ID);
    listener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            degree = dataSnapshot.child("degree").getValue(String.class);
            departments = dataSnapshot.child("departments").getValue(String.class);
            bio = dataSnapshot.child("bio").getValue(String.class);
            thumbnail = dataSnapshot.child("thumbnail").getValue(String.class);
            Doctors doctors = new Doctors(name, degree, departments, specialty, thumbnail, bio);
            list.add(doctors);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(listener);
}

}
```

Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Headline"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    tools:text="This is me" />

<View
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Degree:"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/degree"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Specialty:"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/specialty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Department:"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/department"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bio"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is your ScrollView bound in your adapter?

Comment: havent used any reference of scrollview in adapter. how do i do that? 

scroll is hardly working. sometime working sometime freezes. not responsive.

Comment: Give it an id name and bind it like you do with your other items, i.e thumbnail

Comment: As i have said, i am learning. If you could give an example, i would understand and learn how to do it.

Comment: Try public ScrollView scrollview in your DoctorProfileViewHolder, also remember ScrollView only works with one child element.